# how to find specific lines when it hits a certain pattern

Tags: sed, awk, grep

whenever it see a pattern of ; and abc[0] i need to print first line just after ; and a line which contain abc[0].

i have something like this

```
blah blah;
blah blah blah;
xyz blah blah,
blah blah
abc[2]
abc[1],
abc[0]
blah blah,
blah blah
abc[1],
abc[0]
blah blah
blah blah;
pqr blah blah
blah blah blah
abc[0]
```

required output is as shown below

```
xyz blah blah,
abc[0]
pqr blah blah
abc[0]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You have posted a similar question before, and not a single comment to show us your effort.

Comment: Why isnt `blah blah blah;` printed since line above it also has `;` pattern???

Comment: Could you please answer to the comments?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/;/ { f=1; next } f{ print $0 ; f=0; next} /abc\[0\]/ { print }' inputfile
```

#### Explaination:

```
/;/ { f=1; next } - Set the flag to 1 when you encounter a line with `;` pattern. 
Since I believe you want to print the line after the `;` and not one with the `;` 
you do next to skip the entire pattern action statements

f{ print $0 ; f=0; next} - If the flag is true, you print the line, set the flag to false    
and skip the rest. 

/abc\[0\]/ { print } - If you find the second pattern you print it.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using GNU Grep

With the input from your question stored as */tmp/corpus*, the following will provide the correct output by filtering out context lines.

```
{ egrep -A1 ';|abc\[0\]' | egrep -v ';|^--'; } < /tmp/corpus
```

If you have GNU Grep, but your shell isn't Bash or doesn't support the redirection as above, the following pipeline is equivalent but (in my opinion) less readable:

```
egrep -A1 ';|abc\[0\]' /tmp/corpus | egrep -v ';|^--'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure GNU sed

```
sed -n '/;/ {:k n;h; // bk}; /abc\[0\]/ {x ;//! {p;x;p;x}}' file

xyz blah blah,
abc[0]
pqr blah blah
abc[0]
```

Comment: can you please throw some light on what exactly it does?

Comment: It takes your input as `file`  and compiles the required output based on some assumptions I made about this.